# PHP - How to validate MIME of the docx file returning application/octet-stream

Tags: php, file-upload, mime-types

I am working on the file upload functionality. While uploading docx file it returns MIME type as `application/octet-stream` when it should actually return valid MIME type.

I understand that server is not able to identify the MIME type and hence returning default MIME type.

How can I validate the file to ensure that its actually a document or docx file.

Here is my code:

```
$uploaded_file = $this->$attribute;
$tempName =  $uploaded_file->tempName;
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
echo $mime_type = finfo_file($finfo,$tempName);
finfo_close($finfo);
```

Comment: If you are using cpanel, you can add any MIME types.